# Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode when angular updates a table row rendered with ng-repeat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I'm testing angular live-updates with capybara, cucumber, and poltergeist.

I have the following step definition that fails:

```
Then(/^I should see the following inventory:$/) do |table|
  rows = find(".inventory table").all('tr')
  page_table = rows.map { |r| r.all('th,td').map { |c| c.text.strip } }
  table.dup.diff!(page_table)
end
```

Error:

> The element you are trying to interact with is either not part of the
>   DOM, or is not currently visible on the page (perhaps display: none is
>   set). It's possible the element has been replaced by another element
>   and you meant to interact with the new element. If so you need to do a
>   new 'find' in order to get a reference to the new element.
>   (Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode)

However, if I wrap the assertion (really just the #find) with an anticipate block (retries) the test passes.

w/ anticipate block:

```
Then(/^I should see the following inventory:$/) do |table|
  sleeping(0.1).seconds.between_tries.failing_after(20).tries do
    rows = find(".inventory table").all('tr')
    page_table = rows.map { |r| r.all('th,td').map { |c| c.text.strip } }
    table.dup.diff!(page_table)
  end
end
```

I HATE this solution, because cucumber/capybara *should* already have a retry mechanism. So, if that retry timeout is 5 seconds you're potentially really retrying for 5sec * 20retries + additional 2 seconds. Now, I can add `wait: 0` on the find action, but these solutions all seem like hacks.

I'm using poltergeist 1.9.8, but have tried upgrading to 2.1 and still no dice. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: What version of phantom.js are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybaras retry mechanism is built into its matchers which you aren't using in this test.  You're also using `#all` which has the disadvantage of the elements it returns not being automatically reloadable, and therefore needs to be used only when the elements are not going to change or have already changed.  `#all` also effectively has a wait time of 0 the way you're using it since an empty array of elements (no matches) is a valid response, so no waiting behavior. If in the test the number of visible rows is changing then you could use the `count` option to force `#all` into waiting and implement something like

```
Then(/^I should see the following inventory:$/) do |table|
  rows = find(".inventory table").all('tr', count: table.raw.size)
  page_table = rows.map { |r| r.all('th,td').map { |c| c.text.strip } }
  table.dup.diff!(page_table)
end
```

That will make `#all` wait for the expected number of rows to be on the page, which should mean the rows are done changing and calling `all('th,td')` to find the text becomes safe.

An option if the number of rows isn't going to change (only the content of them) is to just concatenate all the content together and check the text of the table - it wouldn't 100% be testing the table exactly matches, but in a test environment where you control the data it's probably good enough. This is untested but something along the lines of the following should do that

```
Then(/^I should see the following inventory:$/) do |table|
  expect(find(".inventory table")).to have_content(table.raw.flatten.join)
end
```

One other option to try would be utilizing Capybara::Node::synchronize do get the retrying happening - something like

```
Then(/^I should see the following inventory:$/) do |table|
  inv_table = find(".inventory table")
  inv_table.synchronize do
    page_table = inv_table.all('tr').map { |r| r.all('th,td').map { |c| c.text.strip } }
    table.dup.diff!(page_table)
  end
end
```

The `#synchronize` should allow Capybara to retry the block for up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time until it passes -- By default it will only retry on the errors returned by `driver.invalid_elements` and Capybara::ElementNotFound  -  If you also want it to retry on the error returned by diff! (up to the max_wait_time seconds) you'd have to pass options to synchronize like `inv_table.synchronize max_wait_time, errors: page.driver.invalid_element_errors + [Capybara::ElementNotFound, WhateverErrorDiffRaisesOnFailure] do ...`

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for your answer, but these don't work. I should clarify that we're modifying an individual row in the existing table. So `count: table.raw.size == find(".inventory table").all('tr').size` is always true. The error appears when trying to extract the text from the header and data nodes (`rows.map { |r| r.all('th,td').map { |c| c.text.strip } }`).

Comment: I'm punting on solution #2 because `diff!` gives much cleaner output and is more forgiving on columns out of order / missing (important for ID fields that are impossible to test against)

Comment: @daino3  Then you're probably stuck using your own retries since you're using methods that disable capybara built in waiting/retrying and not using any of Capybaras matchers - it MAY be possible to use `#synchronize` to get what you want by passing the errors you want to retry on I'll update the answer in a few minutes if it is

Comment: Thanks Tom! I really appreciate your helping out (and knowledge dump)!

Comment: @daino3  I've added some details on `#synchronize`  - haven't actually tested it, but it should point you at a possible solution -- it should basically be doing the same as your `tries` code but using capybara features